# Preventing Gestures From Going Through An Annotation View to the Map

Tags: swift, uiview, mapkit, uigesturerecognizer, mkannotation

I have a UIView that I an inserting into an MKAnnotationView.

It has a programmatically-generated gesture recognizer.

The problem is that occasionally, taps into the annotation, also (or instead) go through to the map.

I am enclosing the demo, boiled down to an ugly, simple ViewController (see the screengrab to see what it looks like).

If you create an app with it, then click/tap repeatedly on the bottom square (they change colors on clicks/taps), the map will zoom in.

It may be that it is interpreting some of the taps as double-taps, but I can't be sure (the simulator maps are S L O W).

What's the best way to prevent the gesture recognizers under the annotation from getting events (even double-taps) in the annotation?

Hide your eyes. This is gonna be FUGLY:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let washingtonMonument = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.8895, longitude: -77.0353)
        let annotation = GestureAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = washingtonMonument
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        let washingtonRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: washingtonMonument, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
        self.mapView.setRegion(washingtonRegion, animated: false)
    }

    func mapView(_ inMapView: MKMapView, viewFor inAnnotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if let annotation = inAnnotation as? GestureAnnotation {
            return annotation.viewObject
        }
        return nil
    }
}

class GestureTargetView: UIView {
    let colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.yellow, UIColor.black, UIColor.green]
    var tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer?
    var currentColorIndex = 0

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        if nil == self.tapGestureRecognizer {
            self.tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(type(of: self).handleTap))
            self.addGestureRecognizer(self.tapGestureRecognizer!)
        }
        self.backgroundColor = self.colors[0]
    }

    @objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if .ended == sender.state {
            self.currentColorIndex += 1
            if self.currentColorIndex == self.colors.count {
                self.currentColorIndex = 0
            }
            self.backgroundColor = self.colors[self.currentColorIndex]
        }
    }
}

class GestureAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
    var gestureView: GestureTargetView!

    override func prepareForDisplay() {
        self.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 128, height: 128))
        if nil == self.gestureView {
            self.gestureView = GestureTargetView(frame: self.frame)
            self.addSubview(self.gestureView)
        }
        super.prepareForDisplay()
    }
}

class GestureAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var myView: GestureAnnotationView!
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
    var viewObject: MKAnnotationView! {
        get {
            if nil == self.myView {
                self.myView = GestureAnnotationView(annotation: self, reuseIdentifier: "")
            }

            return self.myView
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: BTW: Just to make it clear: The top half has an instance of GestureTargetView directly instantiated in a UIView, while the bottom one has it in a GestureAnnotation. They both change colors on taps.

Comment: I think you need to set the cancelsTouchesInView property of the gestureRecognizer appropriately. There are some good answers describing this in StackOverflow. I find Apple’s own docs a little... opaque.

Comment: Thanks! I figured that may be the case. I'll look through the site, and see if I can pan any nuggets out.

Comment: Actually, I am seeing some other odd behavior, like backgrounds not rendering properly (in another, more complex version that I am working on). It appears as if UIViews in map annotations get some kind of "events lite" from the system. It definitely needs more research, on my part.

Comment: Ah! I think I have it. The Apple docs are murky, but it does appear as if the views in the overlay, itself, don't get events. It seems that I need to use leftCalloutAccessoryView to get the full Monty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to mention how I "solved" this.

Like so many of these types of things, I had to figure out a completely different way to do it, as opposed to trying to shoehorn to the point of hacking.

The way that I dealt with it was to create a transparent UIView that I placed in the view hierarchy over the MapView. I then added my interactive elements to this view, and flushed everything when I was done.

It has a bit of oddness when you click elsewhere, but nothing even close to the damage that was done if the map panned or zoomed. I suspect that I'll be able to work out the oddness with a bit of thought.